# Binary message creation and passing in c/c++

Tags: c, data-structures

I do a lot of message passing in a lot of my software over different types of streams. I was hoping people might be able to share their methods for defining message structures and for message parsing in c or c++. I have tried different ways but my code always ends up being extremely verbose and messy. I have tried different `structs` for each message. A header `struct` and body `struct` but this leaves me having to copy both the header and body into a single buffer. My messages typically have a header that identifies which type of body it will have but variable size bodies. I come mainly from a C background so object oriented approaches have been avoided but I am open to learning them if they seem best.

Comment: When dealing with binary messages between platforms that shares things like endianess, having a common fixed-sized header and variable-sized data is pretty common. And then it's common to have the header structure being a part of the full data structure (being the first member).

Comment: You're describing formulating a *protocol*. How you do so is entirely situational to the task being performed. And opinions on how "best" to do this will be far-reaching, so I'm not sure there is an actual "answer" to this question. If I'm forced to use bin-format, I prefer using known bit-width fields and `htonl`, `ntohl`, etc. family functions to strip out the endian guesswork. Others will undoubtedly have their own preferences.

Comment: You might want to look at an existing general-purpose protocol compiler, such as [Google protobufs](https://github.com/google/protobuf/). Other possibilities, mostly restricted to C++, and most of which I haven't tried: [boost::serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html), https://capnproto.org/, http://google.github.io/flatbuffers/, http://uscilab.github.io/cereal/index.html. And probably the most mature and flexible (but also complicated), [ASN.1](http://www.itu.int/en/ITU-T/asn1/Pages/introduction.aspx) [Open source](https://github.com/vlm/asn1c)